# svn or git or something else?

Tags: git, svn, merge, branch

Our team is developing a game.

I'd like to try separate prototype which is based on our code but will slightly be different.
We use svn for code repository.

Now for my own prototype, how should I set up a repo so that I can keep updates from the svn but won't let me commit my changes accidentally?

I think branching(or forking?) is the relevant concept here but haven't actually set it up myself.

It would be helpful if someone could layout the conceptual strategy.
Below is what I'm thinking although I haven't done branching/merging_back myself.
Am I on the right track in approaching this?

> 1. fork the project
> 2. apply my changes to the forked project & keep getting updates from the main trunk
> 3. merge back my changes to the main(my team's svn repo) if needed.

- any practical tips(such as choice between svn/git) would be much appreciated!

Comment: SVN or git? [Here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4XpnKHJAok8) is the answer :)... I have not used svn much (only some git so far), creating a local branch tracking the master, making changes and committing to local branch & push to master or create patch for others to verify before actual push as and when needed (which is pretty much what you are doing) should work fine IMHO.

Comment: if I create a branch with git, how would I merge back changes to the svn trunk?

Comment: Hmmm not sure but [git-svn](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-svn.html) might be of help, but unfortunately I have never used it. Maybe someone with more authority on this topic might provide a better solution, for now please do see if git-svn fits your bill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do that with just using SVN:
"fork the project" == "create a branch" for your case. It's a common process: create a branch, make changes, maybe periodically merge trunk into it (so called sync merge), merge it back to trunk if the prototype was successful or forget about the branch. Maybe while working on the copy of a codebase, you'll fix some bugs in original code, so you can cherry-pick fixes back to original trunk version (this is the reason not to fork the project to a separate repository).

If you prefer Git, have a look at these tools:

- [SubGit](http://subgit.com). You install it into your SVN repository and it creates a Git interface for the SVN repository (pure Git interface, not git-svn) with on-the-fly merge, ignores and tags translation. So you may try both of the interfaces and eventually turn on of the interfaces off (leaving just Git if your team decide to switch to it completely or maybe only SVN, if Git didn't suit you).
- You may also use git-svn, but provides rather restricted functionality: you can push only linear history, it doesn't translate ignores or tags on-the-fly; doesn't support cherry-picks
- You may look at [SmartGit](http://www.syntevo.com/smartgit/index.html) as git-svn replacement: supports ignores, tags, cherry-pick and even svn:externals

Comment: And answering the question: "if I create a branch with git, how would I merge back changes to the svn trunk?" --- just create a Git commit with git merge and push it. All 3 tools will modify svn:mergeinfo in the repository to the correct value (though with git-svn there could be some issues: you should make sure all commits you merge are pushed to SVN repository and the history you merge is not very complex).

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer depends on how big your project planned to be, and how far you plan to go in your development.

The bigger project will be, and as far you will go, you will notice that handy tool for you personally is more valuable than any advices from anybody.

I would choose distributed version control over centralized in any case. And git is one of the most advanced DVCS on the market. You will not go wrong with it.

In our project we're using git on developers' workstations and centralized version control is on the server as main storage (PVCS Serena namely). We don't have a a plug-in to synch Serena and git automatically and doing this manually and considering this small overkill for using git's benefits.

But in your case *git-svn* and *SubGit* will help.

However, if you need more than just version control (and could not use github for any reason) — issue tracking, documentation wiki, please consider [fossil](http://www.fossil-scm.org/). It's build on the same principles as git, but has issue tracking, documentation wiki, web-interface and incredibly small executable that don't need to install.

But if the changes are insignificant or you don't plan to go really far, why don't stick to standard choice others using?